# Problem with sign in on the Unity 3D's hub engine

Tags: license, unity3d

I am trying to install the unity 3D by this instruction:

[Install Unity3D on Linux](https://www.linuxdeveloper.space/install-unity-linux/)

But I have the sign in problem in unity 3D's hub engine via my Ubuntu OS, as you can see below:
[image]

Also, the log file is accessible [here](https://0bin.net/paste/BNlwS3G7#H1TSxBMQieNwQtfydJUXPys2vLiW+oTZNx2Mz8kQZyJ).

Update:

my Os version is:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I guess it is because of my location and I must use VPN, so I am searching to find how to set the tor VPN on the unity hub connection to the internet, by this search tag:

[install tor proxy engin Ubuntu](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk00LdT9d5m6ufmHuYfz0Baj8yo3VBQ:1619162929502&q=install%20tor%20proxy%20engin%20ubuntu&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiO2_v565PwAhUEhf0HHViRC28QBSgAegQIARA0&biw=1853&bih=949)

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I came into the same situation.

I used Install.sh to install, in the same directory come with UnityHubBeta.tar.gz
and I ran UnityHub from the Appaction list then I could sign in the Unity's site.

[install by shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdFTe.png)

[app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMl5o.jpg)